# Probability dependency between stochastic matrix row and probability vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I'm a computer science expert, not a mathematics expert, so, please, be patient for my terminology.

I have a stochastic matrix derived from a Markov Chain. I need to change the probability of one of its rows (with sum of entries always $1$) with a same length vector of probabilities. In particular, I need to proportionally modify the probability of each entry of that line according to the values of the vector. This is an example:

A row of a stochastic matrix is $A=0.2$, $B=0.3$, $C=0.5$ (sum is $1$).

My associated vector is like another stochastic matrix row, so it assigns probability to each term, like $A = 0.2$, $B=0.2$ and $C=0.6$ (sum $1$ again).

How can I proportionally increase or decrease the probability of $A$, $B$ and $C$ in the stochastic matrix according to the vector? The sum of probabilities should always be $1$.

I suppose it is a simpler probability problem than what I presented to you, but I hope that the explanation of the entire scenario helps in understanding the case. Thanks.

Comment: $.1+.3+.5 = .9 \ne 1$

Comment: What does "proportionally increase or decrease the probability according to the vector" mean?  If the probabilities are to be in the same proportion as the corresponding elements of the vector and they are to sum to one, then they will equal the elements of the vector.  I find it hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: If I sum their probability sum is higher than $1$. I need to increase and decrease the probability of elements of the row in a proportional way according to the second vector without losing the sum property (equals to $1$)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have a sum of elements proportional to the elements of the vector that sum to $1$ is to divide the elements of the vector by their sum.

Example: Vector is $(.3,.4,.5)$ with sum $1.2$ and proportions $3:4:5$  Modified vector is $\left(\frac{.3}{1.2},\frac{.4}{1.2},\frac{.5}{1.2}\right)$ with sum $1$ and proportion $3:4:5.$  The probabilities in the stochastic matrix don't come into it at all.

If this is not what you are looking for, please explain how it violates the conditions you seek.

Comment: Please, can you provide an example with two vectors with different probability / proportion to apply? For example: $V=(.3,.5,.2) U=(.2,.2,.6)$ Where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the elements in first, second and third position. Thanks

Comment: No, I can't.  So far as I understand your requirements, there's no way to satisfy them. That's what I was trying to explain.  The only vector whose elements sum to $1$ and are in the same proportion as those of $V$ is $V$ itself.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I try to find another way or I wait some suggestions from anyone that could help me

Comment: If I have an unfair die for which numbers 1,  2, 3 are twice as likely as 4, 5, 6. Then I want a probability vector with proportions $(2,2,2,1,1,1).$ The only possibility is $(\frac 2 9, \frac 2 9, \frac 2 9, \frac 1 9, \frac 1 9, \frac 1 9).$